# Не работает Style в ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, style

Есть вот такой вот ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView1"
              Width="300"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Background="White"
              BorderThickness ="0, 0, 2, 0"
              BorderBrush="#FFD3D7D8"                 
              DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=Window}"                 
              Foreground="Black"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewAdapter}"
              MouseDoubleClick="listView1_MouseDoubleClick"
              SelectedIndex="0"
              SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}"
              SelectionMode="Single" 
              SelectionChanged="listView1_SelectionChanged"
                  Padding="0" Style="{DynamicResource ListViewStyle1}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> // Вот от сюда
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0, 1, 0, 1"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> // До сюда

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <Image Width="40"
                           Height="40"
                           Source="{Binding Image}" />
                        <Border Height="45" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                            <TextBlock Margin="2,0"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontFamily="Tahoma"
                                   Text="{Binding Text1}" FontSize="14" />
                        </Border>
                        <Border Height="45" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                            <TextBlock Margin="2,0"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   FontFamily="Tahoma"
                                   Foreground="#FF63676A"
                                   Text="{Binding Text2}" FontSize="14" />
                        </Border>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Начиная с 16 по 26 строчки пытаюсь изменить фон итема при его выделении на форме, но он остается таким же синим(показано на изображении ниже). Что не так и почему не работает? 
Прошу помощи знатоков! 
Заранее благодарен.[image: Вот как отображается]

Comment: Перепишите полностью стиль итема (весь свой ItemTemplate перенесите в ItemContainerStyle), оберните его в border (или что то подобное, у вас это WrapPanel (она может не растянутся)), а через триггер меняйте цвет именно этого border'a. Вот вам как пример - [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246795/change-selection-color-of-wpf-listviewitem). Ну либо ставить SolidColorBrush (как по мне не очень хороший вариант).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за ответ, пойду пробовать.